# What's this white flower?

Tags: identification, weeds

Growing in my garden in Wellington, NZ where it's now autumn.

[image: White weeds?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s White Yarrow... Achillea millefolium

Yarrow is an essential addition to any garden for a number of reasons...

- Yarrow is a nutrient accumulator (similar to comfrey) and its deep roots mine the subsoil for potassium, phosphorus, and copper, making it a nutrient-rich addition to any compost or mulch;
- Yarrow attracts an extraordinary array of beneficial insects and birds that use the flowers as a source of food and act as pollinators, which is especially helpful at a time (summer / autumn) when spring flowering plants are usually finished flowering for the year;
- Yarrow as a medicinal herb has many uses - yarrow combined with equal amounts of peppermint and elder flower is a traditional tea used for colds and flu and to reduce a fever, a yarrow poultice can calm the inflammation and soreness of a bruise and is reported to assist in the treatment of arthritis and hypertension.

Comment: Okay, it's going into the compost bin!